# Заимствования, сылки, время жизни в Rust

Tags: rust

Задача: написать программу, которая записывает в файл две строки. Файл, куда нужно осуществить запись, может не существовать. Вариант решения приведен ниже.
Собственно проблема: OpenOptions.new().write() может завершиться неудачей, в такоим случае вызывается trycreate(), которая по замыслу должна создать файл и вернуть дескриптор. Так как эта функция не принимает аргументы, не получается явно указать время жизни. Как можно поступить в таком случае?

```
use std::io::Write;
use std::fs::OpenOptions;
use std::path::Path;

fn trycreate() -> &OpenOptions {
    let f = OpenOptions::new().write(true).open("foo.txt");
    let mut f = match f {
        Ok(file)  => file,
        Err(_)  => panic!("ERR"),
    };
    f
}

fn main() {
    {
        let f = OpenOptions::new().write(true).open(b"foo.txt");
        let mut f = match f {
            Ok(file)  => file,
            Err(_)  => trycreate("foo.txt"),
        };
        let buf = b"test1\n";
        let _ret = f.write(buf).unwrap();
    }
    println!("50%");
    {
        let f = OpenOptions::new().append(true).open("foo.txt");
        let mut f = match f {
            Ok(file)  => file,
            Err(_)  => panic!("append"),
        };
        let buf = b"test2\n";
        let _ret = f.write(buf).unwrap();
    }
    println!("Ok");
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

В этом коде несколько проблем. Время жизни - это просто наведённая ошибка.

Посмотрим:

```
fn trycreate() -> &OpenOptions {
```

Ошибка:

```
5  19 error    E0106  missing lifetime specifier... (rust)
```

Ошибка возникает из-за того, что у ссылки не указано время жизни. Попробуем указать его:

```
fn trycreate() -> &'a OpenOptions {
```

Теперь ошибка такая:

```
5  20 error    E0261  use of undeclared lifetime name `'a`... (rust)
```

Все используемые времена жизни должны быть объявлены в сигнатуре функции. Попробуем объявить время жизни:

```
fn trycreate<'a>() -> &'a OpenOptions {
```

Теперь у нас несколько новых ошибок, но первая из них - такая:

```
   11   5 error    E0308  mismatched types:
                           expected `&'a std::fs::OpenOptions`,
                              found `std::fs::File`
                          (expected &-ptr,
                              found struct `std::fs::File`)... (rust)
```

Очевидно, функция возвращает File, а не OpenOptions - и по её коду, и по окружающему её вызов коду это видно. Попробуем исправить эту ошибку:

```
use std::fs::{File, OpenOptions};

...

fn trycreate<'a>() -> File {
```

Остаётся пара тривиальных вещей:

```
   16  48 error    E0277  the trait `core::convert::AsRef<std::path::Path>` is not implemented for the type `[u8; 7]`... (rust)
   19  24 error    E0061  this function takes 0 parameters but 1 parameter was supplied... (rust)
```

`b"abc"` - это байтовый массив, а не строка, а `open` ожидает строку. Это исправляется так:

```
    let f = OpenOptions::new().write(true).open("foo.txt");
```

Последняя проблема - это просто ошибка в вызове функции, которое исправляется так:

```
        Err(_)  => trycreate(),
```

После этого программа компилируется. Исполнять её я не пробовал. Если возникнут проблемы при её запуске, пожалуйста, создайте новый вопрос.

В целом, очень советую *внимательно* читать сообщения компилятора и пытаться действительно понять, что они значат. Когда компилятор предлагает `run with --explain <номер ошибки>`, можно выполнить `rust --explain E0061` и прочитать развёрнутое объяснение. Со временем исправление всех подобных проблем будет занимать всего пару минут (говорю по своему опыту).

Comment: Благодарю за развернутый ответ. Основная проблема для меня сейчас в том, что я сносно знаю С и немного С++. В тех языках, смотря на ругательства компилятора хотя бы понятно, в какую сторону копать. В Rust - ещё слабо.